# Ruby on rails: what is the easiest way to upload and download files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I do the most basic file uploading and downloading?

Can somebody please tell me step by step what exactly should I do?

I've found some different ways but they were not explained in details and I couldn't find useful documentation for them.

Comment: Using the [PaperClip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) gem. Follow the link, everything you need to know is there.

Comment: I use CarrierWave and works like a charm for me. The docs explain how to get it set up. Pretty simple.
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

Comment: Than you. First I'll try with paperclip. But I stil don't understand some parts. form_for @user, url: users_path, html: { multipart: true } do |form| what is users_path?

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look the the documentation of [paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) gem.

You can easily upload files with the help of these gems.